# Adding user data to local storage only works once, thereafter the object being added is simply overwritten? (Angular 10+)

Tags: json, angular, typescript, local-storage

I have a form which takes in user data. I am trying to write this inputted user data to my local storage. The first submit adds the record as expected, however, when trying to add a second record, the first records attributes are simply overwritten - do note, an array element is added, however its value is simply the id of the previous element.

This can be seen below:

After adding the first user (John), my local storage is as follows:
[image]

After adding my second user (Alice), my local storage is now:
[image]

I am using an interface, User:

```
export interface User {
  id : number;
  firstName : string;
  secondName : string;
  title : string;
  email : string;
  userRole : string;
  password : string;
}
```

The code for adding to the local storage is:

```
user = {} as User;

onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.addUserForm.value);
    this.user = Object.assign(this.user, this.addUserForm.value);
    this.addUser(this.user);
  }

  addUser(user: any) {
    var users = [];
    if (localStorage.getItem('Users')) {
      users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Users') || '{}');
      users = [user, ...Object.keys(users)]
    }
    else {
      users = [user]
    }
    localStorage.setItem('Users', JSON.stringify(users));
  }
```

Any reason as to why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`...Object.keys(users)` will only spread the keys of your array, which are 0, 1.., to the array.

You should just push the new `user` into the array like this:

```js
users.push(user); // or users.unshift(user); if you want it to be the first element
```

or if you want to use the spread syntax:

```js
users = [user, ...users]
```

instead of

```js
users = [user, ...Object.keys(users)]
```